# Check if command is run in a server?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am making a bot in discord js, but I wanna check if the command is run in a specific server. How could I do this?

I have tried searching the internet but I couldn't find anything except for checking if member has permission or role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using interactions (slash commands):

```js
// Where `interaction` is your `Interaction` object

if (interaction.guildId === "your guild id here") {
  // Your guild-specific logic here
}
```

Or if you're using message-based commands:

```js
// Where `message` is your `Message` object

if (message.guildId === "your guild id here") {
  // Your guild-specific logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based if you want to use slash commands or not. I think, that you are new to discord.js, so I would recommend normal commands. 
You can use [message event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate) to run function when someone sends the message. In the funcion, you get the message as 1st parameter. First you have to get the message content via the [.content](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content) property and then use the .startsWith function to check if it is the command that you need, then you can just compare the guild id, that you get from the [.guildId](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guildId) property.
Code (untested):

```
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("your command") && message.guildId === "your guild id") {
        //your code
    }
})
```